# Composite key in XML hibernate with second table

Tags: java, hibernate

Firstly, I have no control over the technology or database structure.

I have an object that has another object as it's composite key.  Inside that composite id object, I have a column which I need to use to get ANOTHER value, specifically a description.  I'd like to be able to retrieve the description which is tied to this key when I pull the object.  Here is what I currently have (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
  <class name="BusinessRuleObject" table="BUSINESS_RULE_OBJECTS" schema="DB">
    <composite-id name="businessRuleObjectId" class="BusinessRuleObjectId">
      <key-property name="idCode" column="ID_CD" />
      <key-many-to-one name="businessRule" class="BusinessRule" column="BUSINESS_RULE" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="updateDate" column="UPDATE_DT" type="timestamp" />
    <property name="updateUser" column="UPDATE_USER_ID" />
  </class>

  <class name="BusinessRule" table="BUSINESS_RULE_LOOKUP" schema="DB">
    <id name="businessRuleCode" column="BUSINESS_RULE"></id>
    <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION_TX" />
    <property name="updateDate" column="UPDATE_DT" type="timestamp" />
    <property name="updateUser" column="UPDATE_USER_ID" />
  </class>
```

What I'm trying to do here:

- Get "BusinessRuleObject"
- Be able to call something like BusinessRuleObject.businessRule.description

In case it wasn't clear, the first table (objects) has two keys, an idCode and businessRule.  The second has one key, businessRule.

Thanks for your help, seems like a simple issue, just can't wrap my head around it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already retrieved BusinessRuleObject then you already have it (if mapping is working properly). Just get the value:

```
BusinessRuleObject bo = ....;
String description = bo.businessRule.description; // Or appropriate getters
```

If you just want to get a description for some object(s) then
HQL similar to this should work:

```
select bo.businessRule.description from BusinessRuleObject bo 
                                   where [ your bo criteria ]
```

Comment: Mapping wasn't working properly because of lazy loading.  Had to add lazy='false' on the many-to-one :p